# Putty copy/paste not working in Red Hat outside Putty window

Tags: putty, copy-paste, redhat-enterprise-linux

When using Windows, every time I use putty to access a Linux/Unix box, selecting something on the screen or CTRL+INS, it will copy what is selected and outside the Putty window, if I CTRL+V it paste whatever I used in the copy process.

For some reason, when using Red Hat, it is not working like that.
What I copy/paste inside the Putty screen is copied/pasted normally inside Putty, but if I try to paste it outside the Putty window, it just doesn't work. It paste what I copied in the Red Hat screen and not in the putty screen.

Anyone knows how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-cutpaste) helps:

> A.6.6 How do I copy and paste between PuTTY and other Windows
>   applications?
>
> Copy and paste works similarly to the X Window System. You use the
>   left mouse button to select text in the PuTTY window. The act of
>   selection automatically copies the text to the clipboard: there is no
>   need to press Ctrl-Ins or Ctrl-C or anything else. In fact, pressing
>   Ctrl-C will send a Ctrl-C character to the other end of your
>   connection (just like it does the rest of the time), which may have
>   unpleasant effects. The only thing you need to do, to copy text to the
>   clipboard, is to select it.

Comment: Sorry duDE, it didn't work. I'm inside a RedHat box using Putty and it is driving me crazy! :)
But I do know your solution works on other systems because I used it that way. It is just not working here.

Comment: I have edited, take a look (next try :)

Comment: Still not working... and per what I have seen on Google, I won't be able to make it happen.
I'm giving up. No Putty. There might be something better or even different out there.